# Web Worker Creating Garbage

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection, garbage

I'm working on a project that utilizes web workers. It seems that the workers are generating quite a bit of extra garbage that has to be collected from the message passing.

I'm sending three things to the worker via post message from the main thread. First is just a number, second is an array with 7 numbers, and 3rd is the date. The firs two are properties of an object as seen below. This is called every 16ms on RAF for about 20 objects. The GC ends up collecting 12MB every 2 seconds or so. I'm wondering if there is a way to do this without creating so much garbage? Thanks for any help!

```
        //planet num (property of object) is just a number like: 1

        //planetele looks like this (property of an object)
        //[19.22942, 313.4868, 0.04441, 0.7726, 170.5310, 73.9893, 84.3234] 

        //date is just the date object

        //posted to worker like so:

        planetWorker.postMessage({ 
            "planetnum": planet.num,
            "planetele": planet.ele,
            "date": datet
        });

        //the worker.js file uses that information to do calculations 
        //and sends back the planet number, with xyz coordinates. (4 numbers)

        postMessage({data: {planetnum : planetnum, planetpos: planetpos}});
```

Comment: How many workers? How many different planets are being manipulated? This seems like a promising place to start: https://nolanlawson.com/2016/02/29/high-performance-web-worker-messages/

Comment: I have two workers, one for 9 planets, then many more minor planets are handled in the other one the same way. Right now I'm just trying to figure out how to get the garbage down with just 1 worker.

Comment: That article was a good read, I'll certainly try that out. It doesn't seem like it will reduce the garbage from the copying over though. I think the arraybuffer may help, not sure if I can use that with object properties though?

Comment: If you want zero-allocation messaging you need `SharedArrayBuffer`. If you want low-allocation overhead you need to pass arraybuffers as *transferable* argument and recycle them when they're sent back.

Comment: anyway, 6MB/s is not that much if you consider that there are 60 frames per second and the message-passing probably involves stringification internally. so even if everything were optimal you'd still expect dozens of KB/s

Comment: My main goal is to reduce the garbage so the GC events don't hang the app up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried two different avenues and ended up using a combination of them. First, before I sent some of the elements over I used JSON.stringify to convert them to strings, then JSON.parse to get them back once they were sent to the worker. For the array I ended up using transferable objects. Here is a simplified example of what I did:

```
var ast = [];

ast.elements = new Float64Array([0.3871, 252.2507, 0.20563, 7.005, 77.4548, 48.3305, 0.2408]);
ast.num = 1;

var astnumJ = JSON.stringify(ast.num); // Probably not needed, just example

// From main thread, post message to worker
asteroidWorker.postMessage({ 
    "asteroidnum": astnumJ,
    "asteroidele": ast.elements.buffer
},[ast.elements.buffer]);
```

This sends the array to the worker, it doesn't copy it, which reduces the garbage made. It is now not accessible in the main thread, so once the worker posts the message, you have to send the array back to the main thread or it wont be accessible as a property of ast anymore. In my case, because I have 20 - 30 ast objects, I need to make sure they all have their elements restored via post message before I call another update to them. I did this with a simple counter in a loop.

```
// In worker.js 
asteroidele = new Float64Array(e.data.asteroidele); // cast to type
asteroidnum = JSON.parse(e.data.asteroidnum); // parse JSON

// Do calculations with this information in worker then return it to the main thread

// Post message from worker back to main
self.postMessage({
    asteroidnum : asteroidnum, 
    asteroidpos : asteroidpos, // Calculated position with elements
    asteroidele : asteroidele // Return the elements buffer back to main
});

// Main thread worker onmessage function
asteroidWorker.onmessage = function(e){  
    var data1 = e.data;
    ast.ele = data1.asteroidele; // Restore elements back to ast object
}
```

Not sure this is the best approach yet, but it does work for sending the array to and from the worker without making a bunch of extra garbage. I think the best approach here will be to send the array to the worker and leave it there, then just return updated positions. Working on that still.